# Why does facebook show multiple permissions dialogues?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, user-experience

So, I've got an app that allows a user to enter a competition and then I want to post their entry to their timeline.

So therefore I ask for the permissions as follows:

```
$loginParams = array(
                    'scope' => 'publish_actions',
                    'redirect_uri' => $facebookSettings['redirectUri']
                );
```

Which is slimmed down from the initial permissions I had:

```
...'scope' => 'read_stream, user_photos, photo_upload' ....
```

But when accessing the page, Facebook still pops up a permission dialogue *twice*. The first time isn't even accurate, and seems to be causing a lot of dropoff as people won't go past that point.

The first message is:

```
  XXXXXX would like to access your public profile and friend list.
```

Secondly, is what I'm actually after:

```
  XXXXX would like to post to your friends on your behalf.
```

Can anyone help as to why, is this expected behaviour, or a bug or something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug but this is by design, the first dialog box consists of read permissions and if you have asked for the `publish_actions` or `publish_stream` a second prompt will appear asking user to provide the write permissions. Quoting from the [Permissions documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

> Additionally publishing permissions such as publish_actions or publish_stream will prompt a second step in the Login dialog, which can cause fewer people to log in.

Also as a best practice, you should ask the write or publish permissions only when you need it. Quoting from the [Permissions documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#publishing),

> Apps should separate the request of read and publish permissions. Plan your app around requesting the bare minimum of read permissions at initial login and then any publish permissions when a person actually needs them, for example when they want to create an Open Graph story from within the app. This provides the best user experience and optimizes conversion.

Comment: So to achieve the flow that I describe, what would be the *best practice* way of getting permission, doing the work, and then presumably re-prompting the user for the permission to post to their timeline? Not trying to be difficult, it just doesn't sit right to have the user re-login after their competition submission.

Comment: You may ask the user to login before submitting to contest and then ask user to allow your app to make a post on his wall. Or you may use JavaScript SDK of facebook to display prompt to publish post on user's wall Which may give user option to decide whether to post or not

Comment: Therefore ask for no perms on login? On submit, with the php sdk do I require another login? If I login with no 'scope' set, does this produce no perms dialogue?

Comment: If you ask no permissions then default public profile and friend list permission is asked from the user. Also, it would be far more nice if you could provide the option to either post or not on the user's wall, although if you still want to post on his behalf it would be nice to ask for the `publish_stream` permission when you are about to post, **clearly mentioning** the same prior to asking.

Comment: This is the approach I went for, it made a substantial difference in uptake.

Answer (score 0):

One’s permissions, which your app requires; and the second’s extended permissions, which you app *could* use for a richer experience but is not essential to your app’s functionality.